# How use on Array

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark Dataframe, that contain 4 columns. I want to extract some string from one column, it's type is `Array of strings`.
I used `regexp_extract` function, but it's returned an error because the `regexp_extract` accept only a strings.

example dataframe:

```
id |  last_name | age | Identificator
------------------------------------------------------------------
12 | AA         | 23  |  "[""AZE","POI","76759","T86420","ADAPT"]"
------------------------------------------------------------------
24 | BB         | 24  | "[""SDN","34","35","AZE","21054","20126"]"
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract all numbers that:

```
- contain 4, 5 or 6 digits
 - it should not attached to a letters.
 - if attached to letter Z ok, I should extract it.
 - save it in a new column in my Dataframe.
```

I started to do it like this but it doesn't work because the title is an array of string.

```
expression = r'([0-9]){4,6}'
 df = df.withColumn("extract", F.regexp_extract(F.col("Identificator"), expression, 1))
```

How can I extract these numbers using regexp_extract or another solution ?
 Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I can do using SparkSQL **2.4.0+** builtin function [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('text_new', expr('filter(text, x -> x rlike "^Z?[0-9]{4,6}$")')) \
  .show(truncate=False)                                                                          
#+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
#|text                               |text_new             |
#+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
#|[AZE, POI, 76759, T86420, ADAPT]   |[76759]              |
#|[SDN, 34, Z8735, AZE, 21054, 20126]|[Z8735, 21054, 20126]|
#+-----------------------------------+---------------------+
```

The result is an array containing matched items. the regex `^Z?[0-9]{4,6}$` matches 4-6 digits optionally preceded by a character 'Z'.

**Edit:** for older version Apache Spark, use **udf()**:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

# regex pattern:
ptn = re.compile('^Z?[0-9]{4,6}$')

# create an udf to filter array
array_filter = udf(lambda arr: [ x for x in arr if re.match(ptn, x) ] if type(arr) is list else arr, ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn('text_new', array_filter('text')) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

**Edit-2:** base on your comment, from 'Z' to 'MOD' and remove the leading `MOD`, use lstrip() to remove this substring. adjust the following:

```
ptn = re.complie(r'^(?:MOD)?[0-9]{4,6}$')

array_filter = udf(lambda arr: [ x.lstrip('MOD') for x in arr if re.match(ptn, x) ] if type(arr) is list else arr, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

Comment: @verojoucla lastest version is 2.4.4 !

Comment: @verojoucla can you test this on a spark 2.4.4 cluster? it would be more practical to test a code under which can reflect to your production environment. :) spark 3.0 is unstable with many uncertainty.

Comment: did you mean: spark 2.1.1 with Scala 2.11? it's an old version of Spark, right? if so, i would use a udf for this task.

Comment: @verojoucla I will correct the word from `2.40` to `2.4.0` in my post. I think this might raise some misunderstanding.

Comment: that means, some of the column values are not array, most likely None. how do you want to process such cases?

Comment: @verojoucla, modified so that if the value is not an array, return as is.

Comment: from Z to MOD, just change regex pattern to: `ptn = re.complie(r'^(?:MOD)?[0-9]{4,6}$')`

Comment: n/p, just add `x.lstrip('MOD')` to remove leading substrings. if you have another substring, just add all distinct characters into the charset of `lstrip()`. just a reminder, this charset is case-sensitive.

Comment: good morning, @verojoucla, I think you already had many answers :)